# Не выводится часть информации с print(python) в systemd

Tags: python, print, systemd

При попытке вывести текст из моего скрипта, часть текста просто не выводится. Что я делаю? Я запускаю django management скрипт (не думаю, это django здесь имеет значение), внутри я запускаю поток, который мне должен что-то вывести, далее покажу на конкретном примере:

Мой systemd:

```
[Unit]
Description=xoma163.bot

[Service]
User=server
Type=simple
Nice=1
SuccessExitStatus=0 1
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/xoma163.site/
ExecStart=/var/www/xoma163.site/venv/bin/python -u /var/www/xoma163.site/manage.py start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall -s 9 xoma163bot
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm /var/www/xoma163.site/thread.lock

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Моя django команда

```
import os
from django.core.management import BaseCommand

from xoma163site.settings import BASE_DIR
from xoma163site.wsgi import cameraHandler, vk_bot


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not os.path.exists(BASE_DIR + '/thread.lock'):
            open(BASE_DIR + '/thread.lock', 'w')
            vk_bot.start()
            cameraHandler.start()
            print("BOT AND CAMERA HANDLER STARTED")
```

Мой код внутри vk_bot:

```
print("Start")
commands = get_commands()
for command in commands:
    for name in command.names:
        print(tanimoto(vk_event.command, name))
print("Stop")
```

Данный код должен вывести порядка 100-200 строк. Если запустить скрипт через консоль, то я получу нужный мне результат:

```
python manage.py start
```

Вывод:

```
BOT AND CAMERA HANDLER STARTED
Start
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
... (много строк)
Stop
```

Если же я запущу данный скрипт через systemd, то я получу какую-то урезанную версию. Как мне кажется, это связано с буфферизацией

```
systemctl start xoma163bot
journalctl -u xoma163bot -f -n200
```

Вывод:

```
Jan 26 10:05:54 server python[16652]: BOT AND CAMERA HANDLER STARTED
Jan 26 10:05:54 server python[16652]: Start
Jan 26 10:05:54 server python[16652]: 0.0
Jan 26 10:05:54 server python[16652]: 0.0
Jan 26 10:05:54 server python[16652]: 0.0
Jan 26 10:05:54 server python[16652]: 0.0
Jan 26 10:05:54 server python[16652]: 0.0
Jan 26 10:05:54 server python[16652]: 0.0
Jan 26 10:05:54 server python[16652]: 0.0
Jan 26 10:05:54 server python[16652]: 0.0
Jan 26 10:05:54 server python[16652]: 0.0
Jan 26 10:05:54 server python[16652]: 0.0
Jan 26 10:05:54 server python[16652]: 0.0
Jan 26 10:05:54 server python[16652]: 0.0
Jan 26 10:05:54 server python[16652]: 0.0
Jan 26 10:05:54 server python[16652]: Stop
```

Что я пробовал?
Почти всё, что нашёл в интернете

1. python -u и PYTHONUNBUFFERED - Без этого логи внутри запущенных потоков совсем не выводятся
2. print(flush=True) - не помогло
3. logging - не помогло

Что помогло?
1.

```
sys.stdout.write(str(tanimoto(vk_event.command, name)))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Этот код работает, но хотелось бы понять почему обычный print с flush=True не работает

Comment: Нормального решения так и не нашёл, но если сделать такой метод, то всё будет работать. def sprint(text):
    print(text)
    time.sleep(0.0000000001)

Проблема в строках, которые выводятся. Если они одинаковые, либо очень похожи, то они будто слипаются и не выводятся.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо разница всё-таки есть. Print -- удобная обвязка поверх sys.stdout...

> print – это всего лишь тонкая оболочка, которая форматирует входные данные (пробел между аргументами и новой строкой в ​​конце) и вызывает функцию записи заданного объекта. По умолчанию этот объект является sys.stdout

Но видимо print вносит свой оверхед и не отображение данных в не интерактивных сессиях, это известная особенность:

> После завершения разработки скрипта на днях я загрузил его на unix-сервер. Все мои отладочные сообщения использовали операторы print , и они не отображаются в журнале сервера.
>   Это случай, когда вам может понадобиться sys.stdout.write .

Взято [здесь](https://www.rupython.com/python-sys-stdout-write-1958.html).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. То есть, во всех местах, где у меня используется print мне просто необходимо использовать sys.stdout.write вместе с sys.stdout.flush()? Интересно, можно ли как-то это обойти и просто писать привычным print? А в случае, если мне нужно будет прикрутить логирование, как поступать?

Comment: Вот [так](https://pastebin.com/ewwzw3U0). А ещё лучше [так](https://pastebin.com/PNBsMhS5).

Comment: С файлом понял. Но с выводом в консоль вопрос по прежнему открыт :(
И никак в голове не укладывается, почему если просто руками запустить, то всё работает и нормально выводит, а именно через systemd какая-то фигня.

У всех всё нормально работает с print(flush=True) и параметром -u, может у меня что-то не так с .service файлом или самим скриптом?

Comment: Ну видимо потому что когда процесс запускается в качестве демона, его stdout / 
 stderr не ассоциируются ни с одним виртуальным терминалом. Вот, на скрине. Обведено красным -- интерактивные сессии, жёлтым, то что запущено из systemd [Скрин](https://i.imgur.com/QnwaHv0.png)

Comment: Я пробовал запускать и без потоков, результата не принесло. Ещё попробую отвязаться от своих классов и от Джанго и отпишу о результатах

Comment: Да просто попробуйте ту функцию, который я в своей ссылке привёл, [вот эту](https://pastebin.com/PNBsMhS5), ну и заточите её под себя. Думаю джанго здесь совершенно ни при чём.

Comment: Stdout не выводит без принудительного flush, а если и выводит, то все в одну строку. Я посмотрю поподробнее, может я в вашем методе что-то не так понял. Спасибо

Comment: А, ну так добавьте flush, [вот так](https://pastebin.com/itjy1jZh).

Comment: Это всё понятно, но так не работает. 
Если мы делаем +"\n", то не работает, а если убираем, то всё выводится в строку, хоть и работает. Оооочень странная фигня. Я сейчас поэкспериментирую ещё. Мне кажется, дело где-то в моём коде. Но суть в том, что не выводится текст по сути в цикле, где он очень БЫСТРО. Возможно он что-то не успевает сделать. Если запустить print и sprint, то оба они идеально всё выводят. Это всё очень странно.

Comment: Что удивительно, если метод sprint описать следующим образом, то всё прекрасно работает. Может, это вас на что-то натолкнёт?

def sprint(mytext):
    print(mytext)
    time.sleep(0.0000000001)

Comment: О как интересно! То-есть и без сброса буферов?

Comment: Да, просто делей в 100 пикосекунд :D
Но при этом питон также запускается с -u (PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1)

Comment: В общем, проблема заключается в выводе данных, которые либо одинаковые, либо очень похожи. Ну, вот с таким хаком на слип всё работает, но это какой-то бред и так не должно работать. Спасибо!